# Lync 2010 Contract Card integration into LOB Application

Tags: javascript, c#, html, internet-explorer, lync

I am trying to integrate the Lync 2010 contact card into a Line of Business (LOB) application using an ActiveX control as described [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tomholl/archive/2013/03/02/integrate-lync-into-your-intranet-sites-using-the-namectrl-plug-in.aspx), but I appear to be getting inconsistent behaviour between 10 test PCs.

I have 7 of the 10 test machines successfully display the full Lync contact card on hover of a staff ID like:

[image: This]

However, the other 3 PCs are only displaying a partial contact card (a round dot in a square box, with no presence indicator). On expanding the partial card I get the below which appears as if Lync can't resolve the user correctly on 3 of the 7 PCs.

[image: this]

The code is running inside a .net Browser Control (hence targeting IE only), I have abstracted this out into the below test code, which is successfully reproducing the issue in Internet Explorer running standalone - which hopefully takes the browser control out the equation.

***Things I have already tried:***

- Made sure lync was running, the fact I am getting the partial card seems to mean that the ActiveX control is detecting Lyncs presence on the PC.
- Debugged the presence check with IE, the 'if (Lync.nameCtl.PresenceEnabled)' always returns true (only ever false when Lync is not running).
- Cleared the Lync resolver cache and pulled down a fresh address book, as per [this](http://tritoneco.com/2013/07/09/reset-microsoft-lync-client-cache/) and [this](http://policelli.com/blog/archive/2011/03/16/how-to-force-an-address-book-refresh-on-lync-client/)
- Identified that the problem is not user specific but PC specific, for example the user can log into another pc and the functionality is ok, likewise another user can log into a pc that is not working and they also do not work. Hence the problem does not seem to be related to roaming profiles etc.
- Had one of the PCs that is not working restored with a fresh corporate image.
- Lync Servers, The Lync servers are in a cluster but on checking the Lync Configuration Information in the system tray, PCs that are working are connecting to the same end server as some of the PCs that are not.
- Checked Software Versions - all PCs seem to have an identical software build:

Windows 7 Enterprise With SP1 (slight patching differences between all PCs, but No KB that appear related. There is also no pattern between PCs that are working and those that are not from what I can tell).

Internet Explorer version 9.0.8112.16421 Yes, I know, but it's what I am working with :-)

Lync 2010 version: 4.0.7577.4356

**Code** (made anonymous in places)

```html
<html>
 <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EDGE"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
  
 <body>
     <div id="822">822</div>
     <div id="624">624</div>
     <div id="620">620</div>
     <div id="23A">23A</div>
     <div id="B47">B47</div>
     <div id="084">084</div>

     <script>
     $(document).ready(function () {

     $("div").on({
      mouseenter: function () {
       
        Lync.showOOUI(this.id, event) 
       
      }, mouseleave: function () {
       
        Lync.hideOOUI()
       
      }
     });
    });
    
    
      var Lync = {

       sipUri: "",
       // Load up the NAME.dll functionality

       nameCtl: new ActiveXObject('Name.NameCtrl.1'),
       // Watch status changes
       onStatusChange: function (name, status, id) {
        
       },
       // Shows the Lync widget UI
       showOOUI: function (id, event) {
        
         Lync.sipUri = id + "@MyDomain.com";
         // Only show Lync presence if enabled
         if (Lync.nameCtl.PresenceEnabled) {
          Lync.nameCtl.OnStatusChange = Lync.onStatusChange;
          Lync.nameCtl.GetStatus(Lync.sipUri, "0");
          Lync.nameCtl.ShowOOUI(Lync.sipUri, 0, event.clientX, event.clientY);
         }
        
       },
       // Hides the Lync widget UI
       hideOOUI: function () {
        Lync.nameCtl.HideOOUI();
       },
       // Opens the full Lync widget menu
       openInfoPane: function () {
        Lync.nameCtl.DoAccelerator();
       }
      };
   
     </script>
  </body>
</html>
```